# How to call API SignalR service from MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, signalr

How to call API SignalR service from MVC application?

client code : `$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:PortNumber/signalr"`

Comment: .NET client code:  `var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://contoso.com/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);`

Comment: Server Configuration: `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration());
        }`